# how to make a struct with void * data?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i have this struct :

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

so the following strcut has an int data , i want the function to accept CopyFunction which is baisicly a pointer to a function that accepts void* and returns void* , i want my function to get a copy of the data in the first node connected to a copy f the second data , now i want the data to be not only int i want to use this function on any data so i used CopyFunction to be pointer to a function that as i saied accepts void* ... how can i use this in the function bellow .. for example if i want to change the struct to be :

```
struct node
    {
        Element data;
        struct node *next;
    };

typedef void* Element;

typedef Element (*copy_function) (Element);


struct node * concatLists( struct node *head1, struct node *head2, int cmp( struct node *),copy_function CopyFunction)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node **current = &head;

    for ( ; head1 != NULL; head1 = head1->next )
    {
        if ( cmp( head1 ) )
        {
            *current = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            ( *current )->data = CopyFunction(head1->data);
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    for ( ; head2 != NULL; head2 = head2->next )
    {
        if ( cmp( head2 ) )
        {
            *current = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            ( *current )->data = CopyFunction(head2->data);
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
```

and then if i have a int struct i can just use this function with a copy function for int like this :

```
static void* copyInt(void* num){
    int* newInt=malloc(sizeof(*newInt));
    *newInt=*(int*)num;
    return newInt;
}
```

also i think it is better if i change and without using always struct node * i want to have maybe: typedef struct node_t* Node;

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: PS - Types of the form `name_t` are reserved.

Comment: @ikegami ... by POSIX, not by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
concatLists(..., (copy_function)copyInt)
```

---

Providing all the "methods" (`cmp` and `CopyFunction`) as parameters gets silly fast. Why not create a `List` "object" that holds not just a pointer to the head and tail, but the "methods" to genericize the list too.

`cmp` is probably a compare function (which means it should take two arguments), which means you are probably trying to merge sorted lists. Well, here's code that uses a generic list implementation to do just that. (I figured I might as well make `malloc` and `free` plugable as well.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// -----
// ListNode type declarations.

typedef struct ListNode {
    void* data;
    struct ListNode* prev;
    struct ListNode* next;
} ListNode;

// -----
// ListType type declarations.

typedef void* (* Allocator    )(size_t);
typedef void  (* Deallocator  )(void*);
typedef void  (* FreeFunction )(void*);
typedef int   (* CmpFunction  )(void*, void*);
typedef void* (* CopyFunction )(void*);

typedef struct {
    Allocator    malloc;
    Deallocator  free;
    FreeFunction free_data;
    CmpFunction  cmp;
    CopyFunction copy;
} ListType;

// -----
// List type declarations.

typedef struct {
    const ListType* list_type;
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
} List;

typedef void (*ListVisitor)(void*);

// -----
// ListDataInt definitions.

static void* ListDataInt_new(int i) {
    int* ip = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ip = i;
    return ip;
}

static void ListDataInt_free_data(int* ip) {
    free(ip);
}

static int ListDataInt_cmp(const int* ap, const int* bp) {
    if (*ap < *bp) return -1;
    if (*ap > *bp) return +1;
    return 0;
}

static int* ListDataInt_copy(const int* orig_ptr) {
    int* new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *new_ptr = *orig_ptr;
    return new_ptr;
}

static const ListType ListDataInt_list_type = {
    malloc,
    free,
    (FreeFunction)ListDataInt_free_data,
    (CmpFunction)ListDataInt_cmp,
    (CopyFunction)ListDataInt_copy
};

// -----
// ListNode definitions.

static ListNode* ListNode_new(List* list, void* data) {
    const ListType* list_type = list->list_type;

    ListNode* node = list_type->malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

static void ListNode_free(List* list, ListNode* node) {
    const ListType* list_type = list->list_type;

    list_type->free_data(node->data);
    list_type->free(node);
}

// -----
// List definitions.

static List* List_new(const ListType* list_type) {
    List* list = list_type->malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->list_type = list_type;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    return list;
}

static void List_free(List* list) {
    ListNode* next = list->head;
    while (next != NULL) {
        ListNode* node = next;
        next = node->next;
        ListNode_free(list, node);
    }

    list->list_type->free(list);
}

static void List_push(List* list, ListNode* node) {
    if (list->tail == NULL) {
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail = node;
    }
}

static void List_push_data(List* list, void* data) {
    List_push(list, ListNode_new(list, data));
}

static void List_visit(List* list, ListVisitor visitor) {
    for (ListNode* node = list->head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        visitor(node->data);
    }
}

// -----
// Main program.

static List* merge_sorted_lists(List* list1, List* list2) {
    const ListType* list_type = list1->list_type;

    List* new_list = List_new(list_type);

    ListNode* src1 = list1->head;
    ListNode* src2 = list2->head;
    while (src1 != NULL && src2 != NULL) {
        int cmp = list_type->cmp(src1->data, src2->data);
        if (cmp <= 0) {
            List_push(new_list, ListNode_new(new_list, list_type->copy(src1->data)));
            src1 = src1->next;
        }

        if (cmp >= 0) {
            List_push(new_list, ListNode_new(new_list, list_type->copy(src2->data)));
            src2 = src2->next;
        }
    }

    while (src1 != NULL) {
        List_push(new_list, ListNode_new(new_list, list_type->copy(src1->data)));
        src1 = src1->next;
    }

    while (src2 != NULL) {
        List_push(new_list, ListNode_new(new_list, list_type->copy(src2->data)));
        src2 = src2->next;
    }

    return new_list;
}

static void dumper(const int* ip) {
    printf("%d\n", *ip);
}

int main(void) {
    List* sorted_int_list1 = List_new(&ListDataInt_list_type);
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list1, ListDataInt_new(4));
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list1, ListDataInt_new(6));
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list1, ListDataInt_new(8));

    List* sorted_int_list2 = List_new(&ListDataInt_list_type);
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list2, ListDataInt_new(5));
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list2, ListDataInt_new(7));
    List_push_data(sorted_int_list2, ListDataInt_new(9));

    List* merged_sorted_int_list =
        merge_sorted_lists(sorted_int_list1, sorted_int_list2);

    List_visit(merged_sorted_int_list, (ListVisitor)dumper);

    List_free(sorted_int_list1);
    List_free(sorted_int_list2);
    List_free(merged_sorted_int_list);
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c99 -o a a.c && a
4
5
6
7
8
9
```